# Top 1 & Top 1 1 ( Expr1000 1 ) typical output

Tags: sql

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Customers;
```

This gives me all customer details of first row

```
( customerid, customer name etc..,)
```

---

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Customers;
```

I got o/p as

```
  Expr1000
 ------------
     1
```

But I genuinely don't understand above output, and I searched for it but couldn't get the clear understanding of it.

Comment: Please **do not** tag multiple DBMS, tag only which are you really using.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product **are** you using?

Answer (score 2):

If your first query `*` mean show all fields

But:

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Customers;
```

is equal to:

```
SELECT TOP 1   
       1 as myConstantField FROM Customers;
```

So you create a single constant field and you will get 1 for every row in Customers, but `TOP 1` will filter to only the first one

Answer (score 1):

The second "1" is not considered as a column, it's just a constant. So with this query, you ask to write down one (`TOP 1`) row with one column with the constant "1". Same thing will happen if you write something like this :

```
SELECT TOP 1 'Hey you', 1 as valueone ,2 ,3, customerid
FROM Customers ;
```

You'll have one row with the values 'Hey you' , '1' in column "valueone", '2', '3' then your customerid from the first row

Answer (score 1):

When you

```
SELECT 1
```

it will show just one row of 1.  When you

```
SELECT 1 FROM Customers
```

it will give you the number of rows that there in Customers.  So when you

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Customers
```

it will give you only the first row of 1 as if you did

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Customers
```

Comment: No doubts & perfect with just a small example .Thank You so much @thetachi559.